# Vivaldi won't start on Ubuntu 22.04.02

Tags: 22.04, vivaldi

Starting Vivaldi in Ubuntu 22.04.02 quickly generates 60.000 lines of (I suppose) error messages before ctrl-C. The first one is `Cloud management controller initializations aborted as CBCM is not enabled`. "CBCM" defies my internet search. The second message is `[6578:6578:0729/171213.906249:ERROR:shared_context_state.cc(81)] Skia shader compilation error`.

Small bits of the start page are rendered, but really nothing useful.

There have been problems for a while, but up to fairly recently Vivaldi has basically worked. For a while startup problems could be solved by creating a new window, but no more.

Unfortunately I don't know which Vivaldi version I'm attempting to run since it never gets functional enough.

I have unsuccessfully tried "vivaldi-stable" with "-disable-extensions" and "-no-sandbox".

I also saw a recommendation to turn hardware acceleration off. Great, but how? The browser is not functional.

Chromium and Firefox run on the same box without problems.

EDIT: The package is vivaldi-stable 6.1.3035.204-1 amd64.

Comment: Where did you get Vivaldi? How diid you install it?

Comment: @waltinator Edited the question with package & version. Thanks for prodding.

Comment: A technique I use when I have too many messages. is to first, redirect (or copy/paste) the messages to a file, then use `cut` (in a pipeline) to amputate the timestamp (in your case, probably `cut -d: -f4-`, then (and this is the magic) pipe the result to `sort | uniq -c | sort -rn`. This runs a "popularity contest" on the messages, and collapses multiple occurances to one line, with a count. Read `man cut sort uniq`. **Untested** `cut -d:  f4- errors.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | tee errorcount.txt | less`. YMMV

Comment: You could just inspect the first few messages, that's probably when something failed. The rest are from vivaldi trying to run without that first failed something. It's not clever enough to quit. Do: `apt-cache search vivaldi`. Are you running the current version? If so, report the bug with `ubuntu-bug vivaldi-stable`. Use `dpkg -L vivaldi-stable` to list the files in the package. Some are worth reading.

Comment: Did you search for `vivaldi Cloud management controller initializations aborted`?

Answer (score 0):

[This post](https://forum.vivaldi.net/topic/86706/vivaldi-6-0-2979-18-1-not-starting) recommended starting Vivaldi with the option `--user-data-dir=/tmp/testvivaldi` which is equivalent to forgetting the past. The browser started without problem even though the `Cloud management controller initialization...` message appeared again.

My solution is to remove the `~/.config/vivaldi` directory and save it as a backup, just in case. Vivaldi then starts afresh from scratch, without any history. This is good enough for me, but might not suit everyone. It seems something in the config makes Vivaldi trip on its own toes.

I still don't know what the cloud management controller is, but actually there is one cloud less in my sky.